# Getting NoSuchMethodError after upgrading spring batch to 2.2.0

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

After the upgrades below:

```
spring             4.0.2.RELEASE
spring batch       2.1.9.RELEASE
spring batch admin 1.2.2.RELEASE
```

I am getting the following error while starting spring batch admin

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.batch.admin.service.JdbcSearchableJobInstanceDao.setJdbcTemplate(Lorg/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcOperations;)V
```

Appreciate any help :(

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have been fixed in spring batch admin 1.3. See [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-151).